# Inserir varios produtos + uma data de aluguel para cada

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css, ajax

estou com uma duvida tremenda e sem norte nenhum de como resolver.

Estou precisando selecionar produtos para alugar para um cliente e informar uma data do tempo do aluguel do mesmo, porem não sei como apresentar isso no sistema de uma forma simples e funcional.

Exemplo :

Produtos do BD

1 - escada
2 - bitoneira
3 - serrote
4 - pincel
5 - epi

Agora de alguma forma eu gostaria de selecionar 1 ou X produtos e após selecioná-los conseguir inserir uma data de locação para cada produto independente.

OBS: Hoje eu consigo através de um select múltiplo selecionar os produtos cadastra-los, porém não consigo inserir uma data de locação e este é o grande problema que estou passando !!

Alguem já fez algo similar ou utilizou um componente que me ajude a resolver este problema ??

Grato desde já pessoal

Comment: Coloque o seu código como está para facilitar a ajuda, e uma dica, troque o select multiplo por checkbox, são visualmente melhores

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se compreendi muito bem sua duvida, mas acho que você esta se referindo a inputs dinâmicos !

Exemplo (Altere ou acrescente um input p/ data)> https://jsfiddle.net/paulosix12/2b69h5nn/

Tambem recomendaria voce utilizar um autocomplete > http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Exemplos mais "profissionais" >

http://jsfiddle.net/6y4wdf7g/

http://jsfiddle.net/4wnov586/

Comment: Muito bom amigo, exatamente o que preciso .... assim consigo adicionar produtos e a data de locação .... Obrigado pela força !!

vou estudar o codigo e tentar aplicar no meu sistema.